# Flip circular UIView that is constrained with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, uiviewanimation

I have a UIView that I've made circular in the following manner.

```
view.layer.cornerRadius = view.frame.size.width / 2;
view.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

I have a UIImageView inside the view that fills the view.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
[view addSubview: imageView];
```

The view has the following constraints:

- centre horizontally
- fixed width/height
- bottom space = -50

I want to animate the view by flipping it around. I've tried two approaches to doing this.

**Approach 1: Using** `transitionWithView:`

This results in the full image being shown while the flip is being animated (the image loses the aspect fill, it looks as if the image is being flipped within the view instead of the view itself).

```
[UIView transitionWithView:view duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight | UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews animations:^{
} completion:nil];
```

**Approach 2: Applying a layer transform**

This results in a very buggy animation where half of the view controller cuts off. I believe this might be due to the constraints in Auto Layout.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    view.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI,0.0,1.0,0.0);
}];
```

How can I achieve a smooth flipping animation of my view keeping in mind the constraints and the image subview of the view?

**Screenshots of how it looks like using Approach 1**

Here's the original view with the subview

[image]

And here's what it looks like in the middle of the flip animation

[image]

**Screenshots of how it looks like using Approach 2**

Image inside view gets cut in half, and the half that is still visible flips.

[image]

**Constraints for UIView and UIImageView**

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you please add screenshot for Approach 2. because i have tried that one and provide solution for same approach.

Comment: Added the screenshot of approach 2 @None

Comment: have you added UIImageView constraints as i displayed in screenshot?

Comment: Yes I have @None http://i.stack.imgur.com/5jz7Q.png

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with `UIImageView` constraints. in order to get full `UIImageView` inside `UIView`, you need to set following constraints.

[image]

Output is :

[image]

Hope this help you.

Comment: I tried this, but I get the same thing - the subview scales out slightly and flips (I can see the edges of the subview). It seems as if the subview is being flipped instead of the main view.

Comment: @Sudeep, can you please add your screenshot. the issue that you are facing

Comment: @Sudeep, can you please show me your UIView constraints as well.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76333/discussion-between-sudeep-and-none).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Make sure it is called in **viewDidLayoutSubviews**.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self makeImageRound]; // call it here to make perfect circle
}


- (void)makeImageRound
{
    self.profileView.layer.cornerRadius = self.profileView.frame.size.width / 2;
    self.profileView.layer.borderWidth = 0.0f;
    self.profileView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    self.profileView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.profileView.layer.masksToBounds = true;
}
```